# Retrofit request response to model object parse

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am consuming an API through Retrofit2, and I want to parse/transform the response to my model type object. The thing is that the recieved answer in Json is like this:

[image]

...

Then, my model object has this structure:

```
public class ApiTokenResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private JsonArray data;

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
```

The problem is that I am just focused on receiving the *id*, not the jsonarray called *data*, but the only value I receive is the *data* array, the *id* is null. Do I have to later iterate the *data* array and get the *id* value or is there any way to get it directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model structure has a problem.
You most make your model like that.

```
public class Response {
    private List<Info> data;
}
```

And

```
public class Info {
    private int id;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    private String deleted_at;
}
```

Note: if your JSON tag name is the same as your java variable, you can not use `@SerializedName`.

Note: if retrofit can't find or pars a `@SerializedName` in model make it **NULL**.

Comment: thanks! it worked! just a note that, even the serialized name is the same than my java variable, I can set the serializename tag also!

Comment: Yes, of course,
If the ```serializedname``` is the same as your java variable it's optional that you set or did not set the ```serializedname```